If $P$ and $Q$ are two propositions, then what can be said about the expression $(P \wedge(P \to Q)) \to Q$
The question
If $P$ and $Q$ are two propositions, then what can be said about the expression $(P \wedge(P \to Q)) \to Q$.
1.) always true
2.) always false
3.) true for only one assignment
4.) false for only one assignment.
Attempt
The above statement comes true, when I take $P$ to be true. And when $P$ is false, it seems inconclusive, so to me it seems option 3 is correct. Am I right in approaching this. I am new to propositional logic. Any guidance is appreciated.

This is a basic rule of logic known as modus ponens. It corresponds to function application under the Curry-Howard correspondence.

Nothing is inconclusive in classical propositional logic.  Need to review your definitions.

Just draw the truth table:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
P&Q& P\longrightarrow Q& R= P\wedge(P \longrightarrow Q)& R\longrightarrow Q \\
\hline 
T & T& T&T&T\\
\hline 
T&F&F&F&T\\
\hline
F&T&T&F&T\\
\hline 
F&F&T&F&T\\
\hline 
\end{array}$$

It is a tautology (always true):
$$
(P \land (P \longrightarrow Q)) \longrightarrow Q \\
\lnot (P \land (\lnot P \lor Q)) \lor Q \\
\lnot P \lor \lnot (\lnot P \lor Q) \lor Q \\
(\lnot P \lor Q) \lor \lnot (\lnot P \lor Q) \\
T
$$

We can see that this would only be false if $P\land (P \longrightarrow Q)$ is true and $Q$ is false. This gives us for free that $Q$ is false and without much work we see that $P$ must be false, then $P \longrightarrow Q$ is false $P\land (P \longrightarrow Q)$ is false, so we are done.
